# Can't connect Mosquitto Broker on Public Domain

Tags: kubernetes, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto Broker on my Kubernetes. I can connect to Mosquitto Broker in Private Network. It works well.
But when We use a Public Domain ( We use Sophos UTM 9 ), The client can't connect to Mosquitto Broker.

I'm a new with Kubernetes. This is mosquitto.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mosquitto
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mosquitto
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mosquitto
        image: eclipse-mosquitto:v1.16.10
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 2Gi
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: mqtt
      port: 1883
      targetPort: 1883
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mosquitto
```

I use NodeJS to connect with public domain. This NodeJS code is:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://mydomain.com:1883');

client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe(topic)
    console.log("Subscribed topic " + topic);
})
```

I wonder what the problem is kubernetes or Sophos UTM 9. Do I miss anything?

What do I have to do for Mosquitto on Kubernetes to use the Public Domain ?

I am most grateful.

Comment: It's hard to give advice without you sharing exactly how you're trying to connect.

Comment: How are you trying to reach the mosquitto? You are using a service type `ClusterIP` it means it will only accessibly internally. IN order to expose the service, you need to use NodePort, or if you are running in a cloud provider the type `LoadBalancer`. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). Please post examples how you are trying to reach your service.

Comment: @KoopaKiller Thank you for your help . When I use the same yaml to deploy my Rest API or Website, The domain works for Rest API and Website but it not work for Mosquitto. I don't know what had happened.
I updated my NodeJS code to connect Mosquitto.

Answer (score 0):

After test your yaml file, I've concluded that you configuration is almost correct, I mean that because:

- The image you are using `eclipse-mosquitto:v1.16.10` does not exists. You can check all tag available [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto?tab=tags).

So, the most probable issue, is that your pod might **not be running**. You can check it by running the command below and checking the column `STATUS`.

```
$ kubectl get pods -l=app=mosquitto
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mosquitto-c9dc57d59-98l8r   1/1     Running   0          5m53s
```

Here the yaml that worked for me. **Note**: I've removed the `externalIP` and `resource limits` from service and deployment for tests purposes and replaced the image for `eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.10`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mosquitto
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mosquitto
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mosquitto
        image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.10
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: mqtt
      port: 1883
      targetPort: 1883
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mosquitto
```

After deployed I've tested using a dnsutil container (you can find the spec [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#create-a-simple-pod-to-use-as-a-test-environment)):

```
kubectl exec dnsutils -- sh -c 'apk update && apk add mosquitto-clients'
kubectl exec dnsutils -- mosquitto_pub -h mosquitto -t 'test/topic' -m 'upvoteIt'
```

Check the logs in mosquitto pod:

```
kubectl logs mosquitto-xxxxx 

1597829622: New client connected from 172.17.0.4 as mosqpub|88-dnsutils (p1, c1, k60).
1597829622: Client mosqpub|88-dnsutils disconnected.
```

If you want to see the message before test, open a second terminal and run this command to see the message being received by mosquitto server:

```
$ kubectl exec mosquitto-xxxxx -- mosquitto_sub -v -t 'test/topic'
test/topic upvoteIt
```

Where mosquitto-xxxxx is the name of your pod.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The image is eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.10. It's my mistake when I type the question. Your answer suggested me the solution. I have found a solution by NAT.